# Sql table with columns that can store arraylist

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a parameters that contain 6 or more number and can be input with textbox
so for each parameter, put the numbers in a arraylist
like this:

```
    Dim a As New ArrayList
    a.Add(Val(B1_Left.Text))
    a.Add(Val(B1_Down.Text))
    a.Add(Val(B1_Right.Text))
    a.Add(Val(BB1_Left.Text))
    a.Add(Val(BB1_Down.Text))
    a.Add(Val(BB11_Right.Text))
```

so for each record i have an arraylist parameter that should be insert the row of one column. Which column type should i apply in sql server table to store a vb.net arraylist?
my vb.net code for insert to database:

```
Dim DBConnection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CS)
Dim DBCommand As New SqlCommand
Dim _PID As Integer
Dim _Date As Date
Dim _txt As String
Dim _B1 As ArrayList = a.clone
DBCommand.Connection = DBConnection
DBCommand.CommandText = "insert into TOM_ShaftFix " &
                        " ( PID, [Date], txt, B1) " &
                        " VALUES(@PID,@Date,@txt,@B1)"
DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", _PID)
DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", _Date)
DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt", _txt)
DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@B1", _B1)
DBConnection.Open()
DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
DBConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of SQL Server you could store the data as JSON. 
In SQL 2016 it is supported natively, alternativelly you could store it as XML.

```
declare @country nvarchar(max) = '{
  "id" : 101,
  "name": "United States",
  "continent": "North America"
}';
  INSERT INTO Countries
    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@country)
    WITH (id int,
      name nvarchar(100),
      continent nvarchar(100))
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt797647.aspx)

Depending on the type you could simply store it as comma seperated values.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```